# How to program USB RNDIS?

Tags: usb, embedded-linux

I am using one controller board with Linux running on it. I want to interface my device to the Host computer (Windows OS) through USB.

I have decided to use RNDIS class for communication between host and device. I have driver ready at device side (linux). When i connect my device to the Windows host it detects the hardware as RNDIS/CDC unknown device. Now for the driver development at windows i used "Jungo windriver 10.10". It generated the INF file and my device was successfully detected on system.

Now how can i start communication between host and device? I would like to mention that I am newbie in programming and no experience in Windows side programming.

It is for sure that i will have to develop application driver on both side (Device-Linux and host-windows)

Can someone guide me how can i proceed on this?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

First, RNDIS as standard delivery available on windows xp onwards, not Jungo's host stack, but MS's.

Secondly, do you know what driver you have ready on the device side? Is it Jungo RNDIS target side stack?

To communicate between host and target for RNDIS device, try the following two links from MS help you understand the control and data channel, as well as the EP set up:

http://207.46.16.248/en-us/library/ee483123(WinEmbedded.60).aspx
http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/0/B/B0B199DB-41E6-400F-90CD-C350D0C14A53/%5BMS-RNDIS%5D.pdf

RNDIS uses two channels, one control channel and one data channel. The initial communication starts from control channel then data starts flowing on the data channel, which uses two BULK endpoints, IN and OUT.

However, you should pay attention to the fact that RNDIS spec requires that after
submitting RNDIS control message to control channel endpoint the host will listen for even on the interrupt endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand Windows upload Generic USB Client Driver (Jungo Driver) for the connection of you linux device.So next you will need to open Connection over endpoints probably in and out bulk endpoints, format data ( that you send) over this endpoints in the format of RNDIS protocol. You need to be sure if your linux device is really expose RNDIS interface. For assistance i can advice to use usb logger. Try connect your linux device to Windows or Linux where you know that device been recognized by some driver and there connection then make logs  of what happens on usb. It seems like you start to research usb interface and it's different protocols i think it better to start from some ready stuff, try to search and learn how people parse, understand and write usb protocols for example for kinect device.

Answer (score 0):

there're already modules which can help you while connecting a linux mc to win pc. Try to look up for g_file_storage module, for example, that can let you mount a file system image from linux mc to win pc as a saperate disk on which you can do formatting, file input output etc. Hope you'll find more on google... :)
thanks,
AJ